# Composition alpha to color

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, transparency

I rendered my object with a transparent background.

I now want to replace the transparency with a specific color for exporting.

How can I replace the alpha values (= the transparency) to a specific color using the composition node editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Alpha Over](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html) node, as in this screenshot:

[image]